# Did I do this propositional logic proof correctly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

This is how I have tried to solve it but I have no answer sheet to check whether I did correct or not.Is this correct?

$q→r, p ⊢ (p→q)→(r∧q)$

[image]

Comment: Correct..........

Comment: Looks good. :) I find it easier to check if there is more context provided, e.g. like in what theory/system we are working etc., but in this case it seems all fairly clear..